# How will the value be passed to the fragment shader

Tags: glsl

This is a extract from a  Geometry shader.

```
#version 460 core

layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

noperspective out vec3 g_edge_distance;

in vec3 world_pos[];
in vec3 normal[];

void main()
{
  
    // Calc triangle altitudes
    float ha = abs( c * sin( beta ) );
    float hb = abs( c * sin( alpha ) );
    float hc = abs( b * sin( alpha ) );

     g_edge_distance = vec3( ha, 0, 0 );
      gl_Position     = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

     g_edge_distance = vec3( 0, hb, 0 );
      gl_Position     = gl_in[1].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

      g_edge_distance = vec3( 0, 0, hc );
       gl_Position     = gl_in[2].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

What i want to understand is how will the value of g_edge_distance be passed to the fragment shader.

Comment: It will be passed exactly as it would from a vertex shader.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas it will be passed three times with with three different values of g_edge_distance ?

Comment: It takes 3 vertex shader invocations, producing a total of 3 separate values, to produce a triangle. The fact that a single GS invocation can do the same job doesn't change what that job is.

Answer (score 1):

You will have a value that is linear interpolated in a screen (window) space.
You can read more about type qualifiers on the official [khronos page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL))

I think to quickly see and understand the difference, have a look at the [Geeks3d tutorial](https://www.geeks3d.com/20130514/opengl-interpolation-qualifiers-glsl-tutorial/)